# Reading Shibboleth attributes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, apache, perl, shibboleth

I am trying to port a Perl script, which successfully reads and consumes Shibboleth session attributes, into Node.js. The Perl code looks, for example, like this:

```
die "Must be protected behind shibboleth authentication" unless $ENV{'AUTH_TYPE'} eq 'shibboleth';
die "Requires eppn" unless $ENV{'eppn'} ne "";
my $user = $ENV{'eppn'};
my $shib_session_id = $ENV{'Shib-Session-ID'};
```

It appears as though the Shibboleth attributes are available to Perl as environment variables. As far as I can tell (I don't know Perl), there is nothing within the script that is fetching or altering these values.

So, I checked `process.env`, in my Node.js app, and none of these values exist. Nor do they, as far as I have searched, exist in the request object created by Express.js.

The Perl script is on an Apache server, but nothing in the `httpd.conf` looks like it's passing anything special to the Perl script. My Node.js app is reversed proxied on the same Apache server.

Is it possible to get the Shibboleth attributes in Node.js, or does it rely on some Perl/Apache/Shibboleth magic?

Comment: Since perl runs under apache, it inherits environment from apache (common *nix concept). Side note; must comment on `unless $ENV{'eppn'} ne ""` => `if $ENV{'eppn'} eq ""`

Comment: Right: So because my Node.js app doesn't run under Apache (it's just RP'd), it doesn't share the environment. Is there a way to pass the environment to RP'd apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mpapec's comment, I solved this by passing the Apache environment variables upstream as request headers:

```
RequestHeader set X-Auth-Type       %{AUTH_TYPE}e
RequestHeader set X-EPPN            %{eppn}e
RequestHeader set X-Shib-Session-ID %{Shib-Session-ID}e
```

These now appear in `req.headers` in my Node.js app; although `X-Auth-Type` is mysteriously set to `(null)`... I can work around that, for the time being, but any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: n.b., Pushing authentication upstream opens a security hole as one could just spoof those headers, given access to the server. The upstream app could be firewalled, but it's easier (thus, safer) to just defer to the Apache child (i.e., Perl script)

Comment: n.b., `$ENV{'AUTH_TYPE'}` et al are CGI variables, so probably aren't even available for a downstream server; the Shibboleth environment variables are presumably set by the proxy authentication server, so they *do* exist and can be sent downstream.

Comment: `ShibUseHeaders` may need to be enabled for these to be exposed to Node (albeit as HTTP headers) https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig